How to Add Interactive Prompts in GitLab CI/CD Pipelines?
I am using GitLab CI/CD for deployments. When the GitLab pipeline runs on the main branch, it deploys code/resources into the pre-prod environment. Now, I want to add prompts in pre-prod pipelines. That is, when the pipeline triggers on the main branch and starts the first stage, I need to add a prompt asking a series of questions to the trigger. The pipeline should wait until it receives the answer from the user, and based on the answers, the further steps of the scripts should be executed. Is it possible to achieve this functionality in GitLab? Is there any alternative other than manually passing variables before running the ‘Run Pipeline’ options?

That's not how cicd pipelines work.

Can you explain a bit more what you endgoal is? Do you think it is to complicated for your users to set the variables correctly and you want to assist them?

@MichaelKotzjan , I want to ensure that before releasing a new tag the pre checks like testing, documentation, approval is all done and this details has to be collected from the developer before production deployment and it needs to be logged into a table for reference.

I'm not aware of any gitlab ci feature that would allow you blocking of your pipeline until some information has been entered
